# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when running a jar and its dependency is in the same directory

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

On eclipse I compiled a jar file.
 It uses several external archives on a mapped netwrok drive.
 The project runs on eclipse perfectly.

I have copied the jar + all of the dependecy jars into some Solaris directory.
 Then I tried

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

and it gave me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: confmng/ConfigManager
```

This class specified in the error message is inside one of the mapped jars which I have copied to the same directory as the main jar.

Also, I pinged the server where the dependency jars are located from the solaris and it was positive.

You can also see that ConfigManager class inside confmng package is really in the dependency jar:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the classpath for the dependencies, you can specify at Manifest classpath, or at the `java -jar myapp.jar` command with `-classpath` parameter.

Example:

```
java -classpath dependency1.jar;subfolder/dependency2.jar;myapp.jar package.of.your.main.Class
```

You can also export a Runnable Jar in Eclipse, so there will be some options to handle with the dependencies, like the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR".

Comment: Thank you. I know the option of the Runnable Jar and maybe I'll use it. But if the dependencies are at the same directory as the main jar, why can't it find them? Also, how do I specify the same directory as class path inside the command java -jar -mayapp.jar ?

Comment: Java can't find even if the dependencies jars are in the same directory because it don't know where to find it. You have to specify in wich jars java must find the classes.

Comment: Using the java command you can specify the classpath with `-classpath`, example: `java -classpath dependencyA.jar;myapp.jar com.package.of.your.main.Class`

Comment: Java doesn't allow to use `-jar` with `-classpath` command, so that's why you have to specify your own jar at classpath and write the MainClass path to Java know which class to execute.